# Variable not getting resolved inside $()

Tags: linux, python, variable

I am expecting that variable `url` will be resolved in `$()` but I am getting variable of variable as `url` and not "http://testing.com"

```
url="http://testing.com"

echo "Fetching from ${url}"

some_var=$(python somePythonScript.py url)
```

Comment: @JeffSchaller thanks for reminding, I was waiting on 4 mins to finish and I moved to another tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You correctly referenced the variable here:

> echo "Fetching from ${url}"

So do the same thing here:

> some_var=$(python somePythonScript.py "${url}")

Comment: Thanks that helped. I also think its worth pointing to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472540/difference-between-and-in-bash